# Xcode 7 : Constraints are disabled for subview

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode7, nslayoutconstraint

I've a subview on view. This subview appears on-top of view when button is clicked.

I'm trying to set constraint to this view but the pin dialog is disabled.
Why so?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Maybe you are using another class size

Comment: Yes as @SaintThread said, You have applied constraints for different Size Class and you are viewing it in different size class. Change your size class to appropriate to resolve it.

Comment: No, who are you? Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brother select objMoreView and make sure Installed option is checked in Attributed Inspector.

[image: See This image]